# "IXXXX is already registered" - MVVM-Light

Tags: windows-phone-8, mvvm-light, ioc-container, viewmodellocator

I'm using `mvvm-light` for my WP8 application.

I'm keep getting `IXXXXX is already registered` error, and if I use this solution: http://developingux.com/2012/06/10/how-to-fix-error-design-time-data-in-blend-with-mvvm-light/

The error disappeared but now I can't see any design data in Visual Studio and Blend neither.

My view-model-locator(The `IContentService` not raise the error, only the `IFeedAPI`):

```
    public class ViewModelLocator
{
    public ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

        if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
        {
            if (SimpleIoc.Default.IsRegistered<IFeedAPI>())
            {
                SimpleIoc.Default.Unregister<IFeedAPI>();
            }

            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IFeedAPI, DesignData.DesignFeedAPI>();

            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IContentService, DesignData.DesignContentService>();

        }
        else
        {
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IContentService, LocalContentService>();
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IFeedAPI, FeedlyFeedAPI>();
        }

        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ContentControlViewModel>();


    }

    public ContentControlViewModel ContentControlVm
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ContentControlViewModel>();
        }
    }

    public static ViewModelLocator Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return Application.Current.Resources["Locator"] as ViewModelLocator;
        }
    }
}
```

When I'm not using IoC container, like below, everything works great (no errors and fully design data).

```
 public class ViewModelLocator
{
    private ContentControlViewModel _contentControlVm;
    public ContentControlViewModel ContentControlVm
    {
        get
        {
            if(_contentControlVm == null)
            {
                IContentService contentService = null;
                IFeedAPI feedApi = null;

                if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
                {
                    contentService = new DesignData.DesignContentService();
                    feedApi = new DesignData.DesignFeedAPI();
                }
                else
                {
                    contentService = new LocalContentService();
                    feedApi = new FeedlyFeedAPI();
                }

                _contentControlVm = new ContentControlViewModel(contentService, feedApi);
            }

            return _contentControlVm;
        }
    }

    public ViewModelLocator()
    {

    }

    public static ViewModelLocator Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return Application.Current.Resources["Locator"] as ViewModelLocator;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Any Ideas??

Comment: Why are you unregistering the `IFeedAPI`? Have you try just registering it when needed. `if (!SimpleIoc.Default.IsRegistered<IFeedAPI>()) { SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IFeedAPI, DesignData.DesignFeedAPI>(); }`

Comment: I had tried what you suggested... For some reason, according to the Visual Studio error, the IFeedAPI were already registered, this is why I unregister it, to make sure my own registeration happens eventually.

As I said, when I try your suggestion or the current code in the post, the error disappeared but the design data where the `IFeedAPI` and the `DesignFeedAPI`, take part, isn't occurring.